# Fragmentary though it is or though it is fragmentary

Tags: sentence-construction

> We can take some comfort from the knowledge that what has survived of Anglo-saxon poetry, fragmentary though it is and arbitrary sample though it may be, is of earliest date than any extant poetry of the other Germanic literatures.
> -*A critical history of English literature - David Daiches*

We can write "though it is fragmentary and though it may be an arbitrary sample" but author chose to write "fragmentary" and "arbitrary sample" before the Subject and verb.
Is there any grammar rule for doing this....and when to do and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two examples of [inversion](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html) or anastrophe. In this case, the inversion is used to add a [literary](https://literarydevices.net/inversion/) or formal tone to the text.

A common example of inversion in everyday speech is the set phrase

> [Be that as it may](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-that-as-it-may)

"[adjective] though it is" is often used in literary inversions

> From this summary, **meagre though it is**, our subscribers will see that we are marching steadily on to the goal we set before us. - *Journal of the Pali text society*

> She quietly chides him in a way that, **fearful and diffident though she is**, she is a truly spiritual person. - *Never Beyond Hope: J. I. Packer, ‎Carolyn Nystrom*

Comment: Thanku....I have another question here, Though is used as a conjunction or an Adverb?

Comment: @RADS It is a subordinating conjunction, the inversion takes place within the subordinate clause. **though** as an adverb is generally used on its own at the end of a sentence: "I haven't seen the film. I've read the book, **though**"

Comment: Thanku...........